# inserting exe file into cron cpanel command

Tags: excel, vba, cron, exe, cpanel

I would like to schedule a task in cpanel's cron to run an .exe file. I did a search and found only script execution in php. The .exe file is an excel with vba and sql code that runs when the .exe is opened.

Would anyone know how to make the .exe be inserted into the command?

What you want is to run an excel file that has a vba / sql code in it. Cron allows me to execute an execution. But how to put this in charge to execute?

Comment: *"The latest cPanel & WHM version supports installation on CentOS, Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL), and CloudLinux OS"* So if cPanel is running on a Linux Server it is impossible to run a Windows exe there. • What is your actual overall goal? What do you want to achieve? Please [edit] your question and give us more background information why you want to do this? Where is your cPanel running and where do you want your exe to run?

Comment: What you want is to run an excel file that has a vba / sql code in it. Cron allows me to execute an execution. But how to put this in charge to execute?

Comment: You cannot do this on a Linux server.